# Nuances when returning physical mail in the UK

Tags: meaning, word-usage, british-english

“Return to sender” carries very little meaning to the sender:

- Who returned it? The postal service, the intended recipient, or some other person?
- Why was it returned? Was it considered spam, was the address wrong or incomplete, or was there some other reason?

**Are there norms, rules or laws associated with what is entered on the item when returning?** For example, if marked as “spam”, can I assume that the company will behave, or is it rather like email, where trying to unsubscribe will result in even more spam (since now the address has been verified as active)?

Comment: This question is off-topic, because it is about the procedures connected with undeliverable mail and not about the English language.

Comment: @Erik I've interpreted it as "what is 'Return to sender'?" which is answerable.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, Royal Mail returns an item, and they still use labels like this (as I've seen one within the last couple of weeks):

[image: Royal Mail undeliverable item label] <sup>[Royal Mail via [consumerdeals.co.uk](http://www.consumerdeals.co.uk/images/royalmail_goneaway.jpg)]</sup>

However, where an item has "Return to sender" written on it and is simply reposted for Royal Mail to deal with, **"Return to sender" is an instruction to them to do that.** There is no implication of whether the addressee actually exists or not, or whether the person named on the envelope is the person who issued the instruction. There **is** an implication that delivery should not be re-attempted.